# Swift - Dependency Injection for class accessed globally

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

I am switching my `CoreData` stack to use dependency injection and while it's starting to come together, I'm stuck trying to get the managed object context to one of my classes. It is a class with many methods that are used by many other classes called `ApplicationData()`. It is accessed by the following, which is defined outside of the class definition:

```
var AppData = ApplicationData()
```

Typical use from another class then would look like:

```
AppData.uploadRecords()
```

The problem is, without a segue, I'm not sure how to inject my managed object context. I suppose I could include a managed object context variable in every `ApplicationData` method. But the whole point of using dependency injection is to try to do things "right". Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just inject that in the init method?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I've read several dependency injection articles using the initializer and it still hasn't sunk in.

Comment: @Cristik provided a great answer. Check that out.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of DI that are most often used:

1. injecting at initialization time - via an init parameter
2. injecting via property - declaring a readwrite property that gets set from outside
3. injecting at call time - by passing the dependency to every method that needs to use it (seems you thought about this one)

Now if you're using storyboards, #1 is kinda hard to achieve, since you don't have control over the controller initializer.

#2 looks like a good approach, the only caveat is that you need to use either an optional property, or an implicitly unwrapped one. And you need to make sure that you don't miss any initializations of that property, otherwise the app will incorrectly behave in case you declare the property as optional, or will crash, if you declare the property as an IUO.

#3 adds lots of verbosity as you'll need to declare and the same argument in lots of places. The benefit is that you have a compile time guarantee that the program will correctly behave (as opposed to #2).

What I'd recommend is a compromise solution: declare the property as readwrite, this will allow injecting it from the outside, but give it a default value. This way production code will function as before, and unit tests can easily inject their object:

```swift
class MyClass {
    // can be injected from outside
    // defaults to the current state
    // value namespaced to avoid name clashes, in case the global variable gets
    // renamed to lower camel case
    var appData = MyApplication.AppData
}
```

Comment: So, I leave `var AppData = ApplicationData()` outside of the ApplicationData() class as it is now. Then I add var appData = TheNameOfMyApplication.AppData to any class that wants to inject the managed object context. Since I don't have a segue, would it just go in viewDidLoad() as `appData.coreDataStack = coreDataStack?` Or could it go it the AppDelegate where it could be loaded once?

Comment: Side note - `ApplicationData()` is not a view controller. It's just a class that handles data, and it does have an `init()` method. Would it be better to inject the managed object context using `init()` or the way you described above? Thank you!

Comment: @squarehippo10 if you have control over the objects lifecycles then I'd recommend the `init` approach (#1), as you get compile time validation for free.